# How to create NAND gate using AND gates and OR gates?

Tags: logic

So I have a school lab. I need to create a NAND gate using AND gates and OR gates only. There are no limits to the gates I could use but I have to use only those types of gates. I don't even know if this is possible! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible because NAND gate has to return 1 for input A=0, B=0, which is impossible with OR and AND gates only. Both AND and OR require at least one 1 to return 1, and can't invert the signal.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew something was wrong with the question!